# Amount of Data in Cache

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

Browser's cache is limited for each app.  The limit depends on the browser.

How can I calculate within the app the amount of data I save in this app in the browser's cache?

That way I could warn my user that he reached the maximum number of saves?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about local storage where you are saving data, it could be anything from 2.5 to 5MB. More details here:

[What is the max size of localStorage values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values)

[JavaScript memory and HTML5 LocalStorage limitations on smartphones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267354/javascript-memory-and-html5-localstorage-limitations-on-smartphones)

Comment: Is there any way to know how much we currently use?